# UPDATE +1 mysql

Tags: php

I have got column in Mysql called Followings which is by default 0.But it can increase.How can update this and set it to +1 each time some button is pressed.
I have tried this query

```
$query=$con->query("UPDATE user_opt SET Followings=+1 WHERE Username='$Name'");
```

But then the value is always 1

Comment: `SET Followings=Followings+1` should do the trick

Comment: @Qirel Oh did not know it is so easy:D.Thanks

Comment: I don't think SQL recognizes `+=` like PHP does, but indeed, the solution is simple ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The following query may solve your issue:

```
 UPDATE `user_opt` SET `Followings` = `Followings` + 1 WHERE Username = '$Name'
```